# java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I am getting an exception when I am trying to call a non-static method in a java class from JNI.The exception I am getting is:

Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Here is my JNI calling code:

```
jclass mClass = env->FindClass("com/secrethq/match3/Match3Activity");

jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID( mClass, "<init>", "()V");
CCLog("jClass Located?");

jobject object = env->NewObject(mClass, constructor);
mid = env->GetMethodID(mClass, "onClickPostStatusUpdate", "(I)V");


CCLog("mID: %d", mid);

if (mid!=0)
env->CallVoidMethod(mClass, mid, object, score);
        //-----------------------------------------------------------
CCLog("Finish");
if(isAttached)
    jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
```

and this is my method in java class:

```
private void onClickPostStatusUpdate(int score) {
    System.out.println("Match3Activity.onClickPostStatusUpdate()");
    performPublish(PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE, canPresentShareDialog);
}
```

Here is the Logcat output:

```
06-22 20:20:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(14899): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
06-22 20:20:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
06-22 20:20:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:772)
06-22 20:20:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.<init>(Cocos2dxActivity.java:37)
06-22 20:20:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at com.secrethq.match3.Match3Activity.<init>(Match3Activity.java:45)
06-22 20:20:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeTouchesEnd(Native Method)
06-22 20:20:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at    org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.handleActionUp(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:129)
06-22 20:20:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at     org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView$9.run(Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java:258)
06-22 20:20:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1462) 
06-22 20:20:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
jobject object = env->NewObject(mClass, constructor);
```

attempts to instantiate an Activity. In general, you aren't supposed to instantiate Activities by hand, but are meant to create them using designated Android APIs, e.g. `Context.startActivity`.

By circumventing the API, you've gotten yourself in a situation where you create an Activity in a thread which does not support the creation of an Activity.

That's the cause of the error. But also: you probably want to rethink the code as a whole. Not sure what you're trying to do, but it doesn't seem like the pattern you're using is the right one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am trying to call a non-static function in a Java class from C++ class through JNI.Please suggest an alternative solution.Thanks.

Comment: Well, you succeeded in calling a non-static Java function from C++. That's not the problem. The problem is that you are not interacting with the Android framework correctly. But there's no way to suggest a better way without knowing - at a higher level - what it is you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I am trying to post user's score on facebook in cocos2d-x.I am using Hellofacebook android sample provided by facebook.Now if I make the onClickPostStatusUpdate method static then I would have to make all methods in the sample STATIC because they are linked with each other.Also, it shows some other error on the keyword "this" and getString.Please help.Thanks

Comment: Seems like what you want to do is call a Java API from C++. It looks like the HelloFacebook sample app isn't quite designed for that. You won't be able to reuse the code as is and will have to write something on your own. You can either call the Facebook API directly in C++ or implement your own `onClickPostStatusUpdate` etc methods and call *those* from C++ (probably implemented as static methods)

Comment: I have done it by making all java required methods static.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coding native project and found this as well, I think it's interface missing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).